# The Perfect Valentine's Day Gift

Tags: riddle, wordplay, seasonal

*My first created puzzle, inspired by something I saw at work. Hints are available and feedback is appreciated.* :)

"They've been talking about getting one for years, and now's your chance to give them what you know they want but will never get themselves. A great gift for the procrastinator in your life, just in time for Valentine's Day! Inquire about our wide selection of available styles*."

*square and triangle models currently unavailable

What is this perfect gift?

Comment: If this is the one I've seen, I think the [tag:joke] tag fits too.

Comment: Well done! Yeah, I didn't realize there was a joke tag. I guess I was one of the few who had never seen this thing before :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gift is

> A round tuit.
>
>  [image: a round tuit]

It's said to be "a great gift for the procrastinator in your life" because procrastinators have a hard time getting it. It's round, but square and triangle models are also available.

Answer (score 1):

The perfect gift is a

> Wedding Ring

They've been talking about getting one for years

> Lots of talk goes around about getting engaged

and now's your chance to give them what you know they want but will never get themselves

> No one ever buys themselves a wedding ring

A great gift for the procrastinator in your life

> You always want to make sure that this is the right person to marry

just in time for Valentine's Day!

> A romantic time to get one

Inquire about our wide selection of available styles*."

> Lots of ring types are available

*square and triangle models currently unavailable

> No such thing as a square of triangular ring